# Can Mercurial Branching Do

Tags: mercurial

Does this scenario work using mercurial?

so if you have a central rep

Central  ->  Bob clones.  Bob makes changes.

Alice Clones off bob, alice makes changes

Bob makes further changes

Alice pushes to central.

Bob pushes to central

Comment: I've given a sample scenario (did not tested, but i'm sure it is precise enough).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: yes

Long answer:

Bob:

```
hg clone ssh://central/repo bob_local
cd bob_local
... // changed something
hg ci -m "ta-dah"
```

Alice:

```
hg clone bob_local alice_local
cd alice_local
... // changed something
hg ci -m "ta-dah from Alice"
hg push ssh://central/repo
```

Bob:

```
hg push // at this step Bob have to get warning about changesets from Alice and
        // have to pull before push
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

Really that's the best answer I could give.  Try it and see.

Comment: I will give it a go, I'm just trying to work it all out, its a bit of a different mental model than subversion, but so far it does all the magic I want!